# Is there a way to turn a date-indexed dataframe containing durations of events, into a dataframe of binary data showing event for each day?

Tags: python, pandas

I apologise for the poorly worded question but it's quite heard to put into one line.

I have a date-indexed dataframe that contains data relating to the duration of events, like so:

```
Date           Duration
12-01-2010     5
04-02-2010     1
14-02-2010     241
23-12-2010     6
```

I would like to turn this into a dataframe, indexed daily, containing binarised data which shows whether or not an event is occurring on a given day. For example, for the first event identified above which lasted 5 days:

```
Date           Event
12-01-2010     1
13-01-2010     1
14-01-2010     1
15-01-2010     1
16-01-2010     1
17-01-2010     0
18-01-2010     0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are on pandas 0.25 so you can use `explode`:

```
# Generate the list of days that has an event
s = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['Date'], periods=row['Duration']), axis=1) \
        .explode() \
        .drop_duplicates()

# First line: we know those days have at least one event so mark them with 1
# Second line: expand it to cover every day of the year and fill the missing days with 0
result = pd.DataFrame({'Event': 1}, index=s) \
            .reindex(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31'), fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
            Event
2010-01-01      0
2010-01-02      0
2010-01-03      0
2010-01-04      0
2010-01-05      0
2010-01-06      0
2010-01-07      0
2010-01-08      0
2010-01-09      0
2010-01-10      0
2010-01-11      0
2010-01-12      1
2010-01-13      1
2010-01-14      1
2010-01-15      1
2010-01-16      1
2010-01-17      0
2010-01-18      0
2010-01-19      0
2010-01-20      0
```

Comment: Thank you for this, apologies for the slow reply. I have tried this, but for the first line 's = ...', I get 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index'

Answer (score 0):

Another way assuming `Date` is index , comments inline:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,dayfirst=True) #convert to datetime
s=df.index.repeat(df.Duration).to_series() #repeat index with value of Duration
c=s+pd.to_timedelta(s.groupby(s).cumcount(),unit='D') #group on the index and add 1 day
m=df.asfreq('D').fillna(0) #convert to frequency = Day
```

---

```
m.loc[m.index.isin(c)]=1 #check if index matches with c , assign 1 , rest remains 0
print(m)
            Duration
Date                
2010-01-12       1.0
2010-01-13       1.0
2010-01-14       1.0
2010-01-15       1.0
2010-01-16       1.0
...              ...
```